# access jsp variable in mxml

Tags: java, apache-flex, jsp, flex4

I have to access jsp variable in mxml file...

or

how to access jsp variable in java file...

Comment: *how to access jsp variable in java file...* ??? explain it bit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Building_Flex_Applications_with_JSPs-7746.html

Hope that is helpful.

All the best, 
blz

Comment: I haven't tried it myself. I'm glad it does. You are welcome! :]